# Why do universal indicators in titration have to be swirled?

Tags: physical-chemistry, titration, diffusion

> Why do universal indicators in titration have to be swirled?

Here's a specific example: I am using methyl orange along with hydrochloric acid to test the alkalinity of a set of household cleaners (titration), and I have to constantly swirl the conical flask with the cleaner inside, but why?

Answer (score 2):

Diffusion isn't fast enough, so you're trying to make sure that you're making the pH of the solution as uniform as possible. You can't want a pocket of acidity or basicity to throw you off from the equivalence point.

People also use stir bars to do this if they don't want to swirl all day long.